# OS X 10.10.4 (14E46) - How do I get 'å' character on US keyboard?

Tags: macos, keyboard

I've just moved from an older US MacBook Pro running Mavericks, and I've been able to write the Norwegian 'æøå' characters by using alt-', alt-o and alt-a.

On my new US MBP running Yosemite, all of these work, except for alt-a, which just writes '¯' instead of 'å'. I know of the option to hold down keys to get a list of alternative characters, but the alt-variation is much faster to work with, and I'd really like to get it to work. I've installed the latest OS X update.

Answer (score 1):

Switching input from U.S. Extended to U.S. International solved this for me.

Answer (score 0):

System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard (tab)

At bottom click Modifier Keys...

Appears you can switch buttons

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it doesn't seem like this changes the behaviour for 'æøå' combos. I'd also like to keep the default mapping for modifier keys.